# What is mark at the left of package (Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I see mark at the left of package, what is it? What does it mean?
I use Android Studio.

[image]

Comment: Where do you see this? Indicate how to reproduce it please.

Comment: Also what version of android studio? And why did you put a bunch of tags that have nothing to do with the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an IntelliJ IDEA feature that means the folder is bookmarked. You can toggle a bookmark with <kbd>F11</kbd> and see all of your current bookmarks with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.

Lines in source code can also be bookmarked and un-bookmarked the same way.

Comment: It is correct, on mac you can toggle a bookmark with F3